# Identify an app by notification icon when the notification disappears too quickly

Tags: notification-icons

There is a notification that repeatedly appears for a fraction of second and then immediately disappears. I was never able to have a look at it despite many attempts. The only thing I was able to see is this notification icon [image: notification icon] which I captured with a screen recorder app and cropped to 32x32.

Google and Bing image search finds nothing.

Maybe there is a lossless screen recorder app so that I can capture it without artifacts? Or some kind of app icon database which allows for searches like this?

[How can I deduce/identify an app from a notification icon?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37443/how-can-i-deduce-identify-an-app-from-a-notification-icon) does not work for me because I am actually never fast enough to actually look at the notification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notification messages from when I turned on the phone. Where are they?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171570/notification-messages-from-when-i-turned-on-the-phone-where-are-they)