# How to turn off system-level push notification from phone vendor's message Flyme?

Tags: applications, notifications, meizu, flyme-os

My system is Flyme OS on the Meizu brand. Even though I have uninstalled the application, I still receive notifications from that software, and after some searching for information, I understand that it stems from a message pushed from the system itself. But 100% of the content of that push feature is useless advertisements.

[image] [image]

How can I turn it off?

Comment: Android shouldn't display push notifications that do not belong to an app (and thus do not belong to a push message channel you can configure). Websites can also send push messages (if you allow it). May be the push is unrelated to the app?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Just to make sure, could you [identify the source of the notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37443/44325) or [access their notification settings](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079661?#zippy=%2Cturn-notifications-on-or-off-for-certain-apps)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Provider

I think that they are coming from your Provider / Telco.  Some of them can push ads.  The last time I had this was when I was visiting India and had a local SIM.  If they do push ads, you can see a button to disable them in the Networks section.

I can't be more specific as I dont see that button right now because my Provider does not push ads.

#### Manufascturer

The phone manufacturer can also push ads, such as Samsung.  In which case you can turn off the notifications.

1. Go to Settings -> Notification -> App Notifications
2. Search for "push"
3. You can probably disable all of them

#### Services

You can also get ads / notifications from Store, Wallet, Themes etc.  You can search for them in `App Notifications' as above and disable them.

#### Customisation Service

1. Goto Settings
2. Press on your name
3. Press on Security and Privacy
4. Press Customisation Service
5. Slide the `Customise this phone` to off.

**Note** not all of these settings will be on all phones or providers.