# Hello can anyone tell me what app uses these message bubbles?

Tags: samsung, app-icons

It's on a Samsung phone s20. Its not on my phone so i cant drop the notificationbar down to see.

[image]

Comment: Thank you on advance for any insights and help!

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. If you're the device owner, please try [the following method](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37443/44325). Otherwise, since there are millions of Android apps and more for notification icons, [the community can't help anymore in identifying a specific icon of an app](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2435/44325).